# How to fix negative number on python on user guessing a number

Tags: python

Is there a way to fix the obtaining negative numbers in the code below?

```
import random

number = random.randrange(1, 100)
guess = int(input("I’m thinking of a number between 1 and 100 " + "Can you guess it? "))

number1 = number - guess
number2 = (number) - guess

if guess>number:
    print ("You were " + str(number1)+ " away! ")
else:
    if guess<number:
        print ("You were " + str(number2)+ " away! ")
    else:
        if guess == number:
            print ("You got it right ")
```

Comment: hey, this is not a question, do some explanation!!!

Answer (score 0):

`abs()` will return the absolute value of the difference.

```
abs(number - guess)
```

Answer (score 0):

the whole code should be simplified to:

```
import random
number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Im thinking of a number between 1 and 100 Can you guess it? "))
if guess!=number:
    print ("You were",abs(guess-number),"away! ")
else:
    print ("You got it right ")
```

Or just:

```
print(["You were "+str(abs(guess-number))+" away! ","You got it right "][number==guess])
```

Whole code:

```
import random
number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Im thinking of a number between 1 and 100 Can you guess it? "))
print(("You were "+str(abs(guess-number))+" away! ","You got it right ")[number==guess])
```